# If the first cell is empty do this, else do this vba

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have the following excel sheet:

[image]

Let's say I will filter on B column, looking for "b".

We have the following result:

[image]

How can I do the following interrogation:

```
if the first cell after the header is empty(in this case A7) do nothing
else
do this
end if
```

How can I check if the first cell after the heading is empty? Because the cell number will always be different.

Comment: Use `Application.CountIfs` *before* you filter to see if the criterion `"b"` is present.

Comment: Please define "empty"!  An integer cannot be "empty", it's 0 or 1 or 4711. A string can be "" or NULL (in C++)

Comment: @BigBen can you show me an example, please?

Comment: @StureS 1. It can be EMPTY because a cell can contain integers as well as strings.
2. It is Excel VBA, not C++

Comment: `If Application.CountIfs(Range("B:B"), "b") = 0 Then`?

Comment: @BigBen it is usable with more arguments? let's say  b & c, b or c?

Comment: You can use it more than once and add the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

An alternate approach is to use `Application.CountIfs` *before* filtering to see if the criterion is present.

```
If Application.CountIfs(Range("B:B"), "b") > 0 Then
    ' do the filter
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the row is visible or not due to the filter applied.

1. Apply the filter
2. Starting from row 2 (the first after the header), loop on the rows of the worksheet
3. To detect the first row visible(not filtered):

   ```
   If Not worksheet.Rows(i).Hidden Then
   'You have identified the first non filtered row
   End If
   ```
4. Check if the cell in the first column is empty, comparing to the empty string:

   ```
   If worksheet.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
   'The first cell is empty
   Else
   'The first cell is not empty
   End If
   ```